# How can I configure a Netgear prosafe switch to route all network traffic?

Tags: networking, router, switch, local-area-network, netgear

I am setting up a small network and am out of my depth! Someone prior to me joining the team has bought the kit, now I'm attempting to configure it all to work.

I have noticed that the network traffic is limited to the same speed as our router (at best 100Mb/s), but we have a gigabit network switch and I would like to improve the network speed such that traffic inside the network reaches 1Gb/s transfer rates (or at least close to them). How can I configure the switch to do this?

The router is a Cisco 881w, the network switch is a Netgear s3300-52x ProSafe. Currently all the routing is being done by the router, which has a single VLAN set up for everything, the switch is pretty much just bridging at the moment. What I'd like to achieve is faster speeds over the wired LAN by using the switch properly, as I suspect that currently everything is going through the router regardless of whether it's going externally or not.

Comment: Even if you had machines in the same subnet but in different VLAN's the traffic wouldn't transit the router. It would simply die on the switch. The only way traffic would be transiting the router is if you had machines in different subnets (Layer 3). The quickest way to verify this is to run a tracert between two machines. You should see a single hop. If you see two hops then you know traffic is transiting the router. What are the machines negotiating for their link speed?

Comment: I added some details about flow control to my answer. I think it should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have a single VLAN (along with a single subnet), then all traffic between your LAN systems will not touch the router. The only time the router would be involved is if you're routing between VLANs/subnets.

Comment: ran a tracert as per joeqwerty's suggestion and it seems you're both right, never touches the router. Looks like the speed issue is machine specific (I had tested it on several machines, but apparently a couple of them are faster) and I should be looking into their hardware or configuration to resolve this.

Answer (score -1):

If your server is behind the router then there is nothing you can do, however if it is on the same switch then check at what speed switch ports are negotiated.
If your clients have gigabit interfaces but switch ports are negotiated at 100Mpbs you may have inadequate wiring. You need Cat6 (Cat5e bare minimum) wiring to achieve 1Gbps speed. More on this [here](https://superuser.com/questions/549004/what-happens-when-gigabit-switches-are-connected-over-an-old-cat5-cable).

First thing to try is to connect you laptop directly to switch port with good cable and make sure it negotiates at 1Gbps. Next step is to go to your switch console and check for transmission errors on each of the connected ports. Lots of errors would be another indication of inadequate wiring.

UPDATE: You may also try disabling flow control on your switch, [this](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/lanwan/lanwan-features/30212) explains why.

Comment: `You need Cat6 (Cat5e bare minimum) wiring to achieve 1Gbps speed` - That's not technically correct. 1GbE will run on CAT5.

Comment: @joeqwerty, it may work on short cable but from my experience it almost never does. Even if it negotiates at 1Gbps the transmission errors will kill the performance.

Comment: @dtoubelis Your experience does not match what the vast majority of uses see. Cat5e, terminated properly, is rated for gigabit up to 100M. If you're seeing transmission errors, you either have crappy gear, crappy cabling, or both.

Comment: @joeqwerty 1gbe on cat5 ? not cat5e ?

Comment: Yes. GbE is supported with CAT5 cable.

Comment: @EEAA, theories aside, Cat5 cable longer than 30ft between two Negrear switches will NEVER negotiate at 1Gbps.

Comment: @dtoubelis Well then get rid of that crappy switch. :)

Comment: @EEAA, it happens that switch from this question is one of them ;-)

Comment: 1000Base-T has been ***designed to work over Cat5e***. There is not much to add here - if the PHYs are standard-compliant and the cable is indeed a Cat5e not just by label but by physical properties (which *can* deteriorate through ageing or mechanical stress), the link would negotiate 1000 Mbps *and* run virtually error-free even in boundary conditions. Of course, nothing but a replacement will fix broken gear, but *"Netgear switches need Cat6"* is an inaccurate generalization.

Comment: @the-wabbit, This argument is about 1Gbps over Cat5 and not Cat5e. This is a good summary on the subject http://superuser.com/questions/549004/what-happens-when-gigabit-switches-are-connected-over-an-old-cat5-cable.

Comment: The standard corresponding to Cat5e (TIA-EIA 568-A-5) has been ratified in 1999. If you have a cable plant of that age, it likely has needed an overhaul for a while now. If it has 15-year old components which have seen active mechanical use (outlets, patch cables, cable runs through areas with changing temperature or mechanical tension), those most likely will have deteriorated well below the specification requirements. So whether it initially has been certified as Cat5, Cat5e or even Cat6 will be the least of your concerns - it certainly will not certify again today.

Comment: Not to butt into your fun looking discussion, but I'm using cat5e and cat6 throughout. I've done a few things since posting the question and can tell you that cat5e will support 1Gbps on this router (although the four 10Gbps ports are still not getting that over cat6, an investigation for another day)

Comment: @allwoodd, please read the update to my answer. I think this is your issue. You need to disable flow control on the switch.